# svelte bind to object with index triggers Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: async-await, svelte, bind

```
<script>
    let pairs
    const radioboxes =["0-4","0-8","0-12"]
    async function getdata () {
         pairs = [
        {field:"Text Field 035",
    value:""
    },
    {field:"Text Field 036",
    value:""
    },
    {field:"Text Field 037",
    value:""
    },
    {field:"Text Field 038",
    value:""
    }]
        
        return pairs
    }
    
    async function init () {
        await getdata 
    }
    
    function handleclick () {
        console.log(e)
    }
    init()
    
</script>

{#each radioboxes as selec, index}
    <input type=radio
         bind:group={pairs[index].value} 
         on:change={handleclick} 
         name="Dayspermonth"  
         value={selec} 
         id={index} > 
{/each}
```

The original version fetches from a pdf the Field names - which are then iterated thru and an object of Field names and Values is created.

The `pairs[index].value` return a Cannot Read Properties Of Undefined

However the `pairs.value` does not

Ideas thoughts?

Comment: It should be getdata(), not getdata, iside the init() function.